# ORMLite - foreign key persistance

Tags: android, database

I've looked through questions about ormlite and android but still haven't find an answer.

Assume I have folliwing classes:

- Post
- Comments

In code :

```
Post p = new Post("hello world");
Comment c = new Comment("HI!", p);

c.save();
p.save();
```

But in comment table there is null in foreign key? Are there workaround how to avoid this situation like in Hibernate? (except saving in right order?)

Answer (score 0):

Not really- this **SHOULD** break.  by defining a not-null foreign key, you're saying that a Comment is meaningless without a post.  If the A is meaningless without B, the database should give an error if you are trying to create an A without a B, since there can be no guarantee (from the db's perspective) that you will correlate B to an A later